# Is there a program to view a raw array as an image?

Tags: arrays, image, graphics, photo

I have a heightmap which is just a 16-bit wide big-endian array. I haven't looked into encoding a jpg or png from the raw data, but before I do I would like to know if there are any programs that I can download to view it as an image, because I want to know what it looks like.

When I do a search for viewing raw image data all the results return information about RAW image formats as used for camera image formats, which also differ between manufacturers, I don't think that's what I'm looking for. It's raw data as in a raw array, not the .RAW image format.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with **ImageMagick**, which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

So, if your image is 600x400 and just 16-bit grey values in a file called `image.dat`, you would do this at the Terminal and get a file called `output.jpg` which you can view:

```
convert -size 600x400 -depth 16 -endian MSB GRAY:image.dat -auto-level output.jpg
```

If there is a 512 byte header, you would use:

```
convert -size 600x400+512 ...
```

If the data are colour rather than greyscale, use:

```
convert -size 600x400 -depth 16 -endian MSB RGB:image.dat ...
```

If you want a PNG instead of a JPG, use:

```
convert ... result.png
```

---

As an alternative, you could consider writing a PGM (Portable Grey Map) or 
PPM (Portable Pix Map) format file from your program which is **extremely easy**, see [NetPBM Wiki description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) and would have your image size in it - so it would be self-contained. One would normally use `P5` (for greyscale) or `P6` (for colour) with binary, rather than ASCII, data. Then you can convert that simply to a JPEG (or PNG)  afterwards with **ImageMagick** and never have to worry about writing JPEGs or PNGs or linking with libraries:

```
convert result.pgm result.png     # convert greyscale results to PNG

convert result.ppm result.jpg     # convert colour results to JPG, or PNG, or TIFF, or GIF...
```